# Any research of the accuracy of Story Points?

Tags: scrum, agile, estimation, story-points

One of the main questions about Story Points is what is their accuracy. Has any research or survey been performed to analyse their precision?

For example what is the accuracy of the completion date estimation based on Story Points.

Comment: To answer this question we just need to say yes (giving at least one example) or no (explaining how we searched)?

Comment: Links to researches would be appreciated!)

Comment: By 'precision', do you mean 'accuracy'? Because I can answer your Question as-is with two words - 'Fibonacci, usually'.

Comment: @Sarov Yes, I mean "accuracy"

Comment: Interesting question. I'd be willing to bet that the cost of calibration vs the return on calibration is better for story points than for estimation by hours.  I'm also willing to bet that even poor quality story point estimation by the team is superior to estimates developed by the PM in isolation.  I think your question is good - but I think it has to be in the context of some questions that are much more important.

Comment: I don't think completion date and story points are related, or at least they shouldn't be related. Maybe I'm wrong, but I see SP as an estimation of effort and complexity, and not time, while completion date is purely time-related.

Comment: I've created simple application that reads JIRA tickets, calculates their cycle time and compares it to estimated story points. When I run it on my current projects, I find minimal relationship between the two. I would bet majority of projects using story points would be same. You can try it here : https://github.com/Euphoric/JiraFlowCharts/wiki

Comment: @Euphoric You'd advise you to write a complete answer and explain your research in more detail. Do you include idle-time in cycle time? Inorder to calculate a time spent on an issue you would need to track time, not just to measure the start time and the end time.

Answer (score 8):

I know of at least two

- "Empirical assessment of machine learning models for agile software development effort estimation using story points". Available online at https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11334-017-0288-z
- "Empirical Validation of Neural Network Models for Agile Software Effort Estimation based on Story Points". Available online at https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1877050915020037

Answer (score 3):

[Effort Estimation in Agile Software Development using StoryPoints](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/0ae7/5cc0678f6b01f1066093b19cad9dd4379385.pdf) gives a good overview of the story points accuracy: **The cone of uncertainty is inherent to estimation.**

For **improving the estimation accuracy**, various **optimization techniques** have been proposed. The Support Vector  Regression  (SVR)  is one of these techniques that helps in getting optimal estimated values and the following article explains the theory in a thorough manner.

https://ksiresearchorg.ipage.com/seke/seke14paper/seke14paper_150.pdf

Also, to improve the accuracy of effort estimation, [this article](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi626LyvKbnAhWBGuwKHRlNA2AQFjAHegQICBAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.insticc.org%2FPrimoris%2FResources%2FPaperPdf.ashx%3FidPaper%3D78428&usg=AOvVaw3Lq8BIa3SIhiQvLKM0IDKO) proposes a model for agile software development project prediction **using Bayesian networks**.

[Mike Cohn](https://twitter.com/mikewcohn) has invested a lot of time researching the subject of Story points. You may also look into the following articles:

- [Should Companies Measure Productivity in Story Points / Ideal Days?](https://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/blog/should-companies-measure-productivity-in-story-points-ideal-days)
- [What Are Story Points?](https://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/blog/what-are-story-points)
- [How Do Story Points Relate to Hours?](https://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/blog/how-do-story-points-relate-to-hours)